# css grid - shift right column to the left when left column is dynamic

Tags: css, css-grid

I've got the following setup:

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 1em;
}

.a {
  background-color: green;
  grid-column: 1/7;
  griw-row: 1;
}

.b {
  background-color: grey;
  grid-column: 7/-1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.c {
  background-color: blue;
  grid-column: 1/7;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.d {
  background-color: yellow;
  grid-column: 7/-1;
  grid-row: 2;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="b">
    Content b
  </div>
  <div class="c">
    Content c
  </div>
  <div class="d">
    Content d
  </div>
</section>
```

The element with css class `.a` is dynamic and not always available. How can I shift right column (`.b`) to the left when `.a` column is not available?

**Note**: I can't use `grid-auto-columns` as IE11 doesn't support it.

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60748083/8620333

Comment: `grid-auto-columns` don't work in IE11, can't use `:only-child` pseudo selector as there are more elements inside the `section` element. I thought that posting minimal example would reduce the noise, but clearly that didn't help.

Comment: all these details need to belong to your question if you want an accurate answer.

Comment: updated the question to include the details from the comment

Comment: like this: https://jsfiddle.net/8u7fL0he/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't explicitly define the column positions. Simply set the number of column and the auto placement will do the job for you:

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 1em;
  margin: 5px;
}

section > * {
  grid-column: span 6; /* all the items should take 6 columns*/
}

.a {
  background-color: green;
}

.b {
  background-color: grey;
}

.c {
  background-color: blue;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.d {
  background-color: yellow;
  grid-row: 2;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="b">
    Content b
  </div>
  <div class="c">
    Content c
  </div>
  <div class="d">
    Content d
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="a">
    Content a
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    Content b
  </div>
  <div class="c">
    Content c
  </div>
  <div class="d">
    Content d
  </div>
</section>
```